# VideoJS - fullscreen video is shifted downwards

Tags: css, video, fullscreen, video.js

I am using video.js to show videos on a website, and it works nicely. But when the video is viewed in full screen, the video is for some reason shifted downwards by about 30px, so that a black border is shown at the top, and the lowermost part of the video, including part of the player's controls, are obscured.

Is this a CSS issue? What can it be that makes the full screen player shift downwards?

(I use the latest player from the official CDN, with no alterations to the player's CSS.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try making the padding and margin to 0?